# Multiple angular-isotope containers on one page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, jquery-isotope

I am using angular-isotope and I would like to have two initialized angular isotope containers on the same page but every time I add second container, first one stops working...

Plese provide me with some suggestions or if you know how to solve this problem, that would be great!

Cheers

Comment: cheers for your question

Comment: @Mahi why is that ?